# ¿Por qué está operación da este resultado?

Tags: c++17

Estoy aprendiendo C++ al hacer ejercicios hubo uno que no sé de donde sacó es resultado

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Main(){

int i = 0, j= 2;

float r = 2.0;

i = 5 * j ^ 3;

cout<<i;

Return 0

}
```

Al compilar y ejecutar muestra como resultado 9 y no sé de donde sale, debería haberse hecho primero la multiplicación 5 * j = 10 ^ 3 = 1000 no?

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada... define correctamente tu operación...
Ni siquiera tienes idea de si es:

```
a.- x*y^z
b.- (x*y)^z
c.- x*(y^z)
d.- Alguna que no haya considerado
```

Todas estas dan resultado diferente, por las reglas matemáticas.

Segundo, si quieres elevar un número, es mejor usar la función `pow()`
Y trabajar los números como doubles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 

int main() {
    double i = 0;
    double j= 2.0;
    float r = 2.0;
    i = 5 * pow (j, 3.0); //Esto sería: x*(y^z)
    i = pow((5*j), 3.0); // Esta sería la que mencionas al final
    std::cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, lo puse así porque está puesto en el ejercicio de esa forma, me pide es dar el resultado de esa operación

Answer (score 0):

El operador ^ (XOR) Bitwise exclusive OR: realiza la disyunción exclusiva bit a bit.

Una disyunción exclusiva solamente es verdadera cuando ambos operandos tienen valores diferentes y es falsa si los dos operandos son ambos verdaderos o ambos falsos.

Tabla de verdad XOR:

| a | b | a ^ b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | F |
| V | F | V |
| F | V | V |
| V | V | F |

```
//Según tu código de ejemplo:

i = 5 * j ^ 3;

i = 5 * 2 ^ 3;

i = 10 ^ 3;

//Si lo expresamos como número binarios sería (operación XOR):

1010 (número 10 sistema decimal)
0011 (número 3 sistema decimal)
-----
1001 (número 9 sistema decimal)

1: verdadero
0: falso
```

Por lo tanto el valor de la variable i es 9.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ya entiendo veía ese operador como un pow

Comment: De nada @CesarMendez! No olvides seleccionar la respuesta que mejor conteste tu pregunta, para que la pregunta quede como contestada.